# Unused Jar clean-up from SAP COMMERCE HYBRIS application

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

We are using Sap commerce 2205(hybris) application which needs unused Jars clean-up. We have huge custom codebase so manually removing the jars and compiling the application to see whether the jar is needed or not is quite lengthy and hectic process.

I have tried to find out solutions on different platforms. Few solutions suggest using maven dependency analyze option which is the easiest, but the application project are java projects. we cannot go by conversion as there are lot of custom extensions.

Other posts are related with the tools like UC detector, class path analyzers, loosejar.jars and even more but there is no compatibility matrix with the HYBRIS application and also not covered the aspect of the reflections.

In need of the solution how to get the unsed jars list from the application so that we can clean up in terms of SAP commerce hybris